# Adding new geometry column using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

This is probably pretty straight forward. I want to add a new geometycolumn (27700) to my table which is currently in 3857, but i dont want to alter the points to the new geomtery.

How would i go about this?

Comment: What would you have at the end? Two geometry columns, one in 3857 and another in 27700, the letter being empty?

Comment: i want both columns to be populated

Comment: I just tried using this:    update test set geom_27700= ST_Transform(geom_27700, 27700)
From spatial_ref_sys where St_SRID (geom)= 3857;  but the geom_27700 column is still null what did i do wrong?

Comment: spatial_ref_sys should not appear in a query like this. It is a look up table that ST_Transform calls implicitly. Also, I am guessing that geom_27700 is your new geometry, so transforming sometihng null to 27700 isn't likely to work. I am guessing you need your 3857 column inside ST_Transform, as this is what you are transforming from. Please take more time to read the docs, as the examples are pretty good. We all struggle when beginning spatial sql, but this is really quite a trivial question, and you will learn more by playing around.